# Comment utiliser l'expression « se débloquer » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

L'une de mes collègues m'a dit :

> Des mois sans résultat... mais elle a à peine joint l'équipe que **tout se débloque** !

Il paraît qu’aucun dictionnaire n'a d'entrée pour le verbe réfléchi « se débloquer ». Je me demande s’il s’agit d’un projet ou de recherches qui viennent finalement d'aboutir après un bon bout de temps passé sans progrès sensible ?

Comment: [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9bloquer): Étymol. et Hist. … 4. 1969 au fig. **se débloquer** « redevenir susceptible d'évoluer » (Le Monde, loc. cit.)

Comment: « Il parait » : où as-tu regardé ? Et on le trouve aussi dans des dictionnaires bilingues... , des exemples sur Linguee... "

Comment: @Laure Oh, I usually don't consider Linguee a dictionary, but more of a site offering lots of example sentences that include particular phrases. I notice the lack of an entry for the reflexive "se débloquer" in the usual suspects for me such as Wiki, Larousse, etc.

Comment: Larousse on line is not good. Reverso has a definition as well, but on the Internet the best is the TLF.

Comment: @Laure Ja, I don't usually count on Larousse, even if it does have its moments from time to time. I've always thought that more readability on TLF wouldn't go amiss, though! :)

Comment: @jlliagre [_Ac.9_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/d%C3%A9bloquer) directement, au sens 5, fig. comme vous dites. Merci.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le verbe **se débloquer** est construit à partir du verbe **se bloquer**.
Il est courant d'ajouter un "dé" devant un verbe pour signifier l'annulation du verbe de base.

- **Je vais te déshabiller**
- **Je vais le désincarcérer**
- **Je vais le défaire**

On peut paraphraser en disant : **La situation est débloquée par elle-même**

Mais même dans ce cas, le locuteur français ajouter naturellement l'emphase de l’auto-réalisation du déblocage en ajoutant une réflexion au verbe

**La situation s'est débloquée par elle-même**

Mais la phrase est vraiment lourde, donc **la situation s'est débloquée**